# USERFORM: Mover item de ListBox para cima ou para baixo

Tags: vba, userform, listbox, microsoft-excel

Tenho uma ListBox em um UserForm que reflete uma lista da ordem de exibição dos itens numa Dashboard. Quero que o usuário tenha liberdade de alterar a ordem desses itens movendo-os para baixo ou para cima na ListBox, conforme mostra a figura:

[image: Alterar ordem de exibição dos itens]

Existe uma maneira de fazer isso sem alterar o `RowSource`?

Comment: Olá, Seu a fonte de informação do seu rowsource ? Uma consulta, uma tabela, uma worksheet ?

Comment: Meu RowSource puxa a informação de um intervalo nomeado.

Comment: Minha sugestão seria editar o intervalo nomeado e recriar o rowsource, pois assim, creio que o usuário toda vez que utilizar a ferramenta, manterá a preferência de sequencia das colunas e seu form é atualizado em tela.